# How do you write DATE() with a wildcard on year?

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, date

In my flow, I need to check whether a record's date month and day match a specific date but not the year.

So, I have a basic decision item that looks like this:
`{!Record.StartDate}`  `=`  `DateVariable`

I thought I'd define a variable in which I could use DATE(year,month,day), but I'd need to replace year with a wildcard, which I can't find whether it's even possible.

How would you go about it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a single Date variable you need two separate constants for the day of month and month you want to match.

You can then use the [DAY](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_day.htm&type=5) and [MONTH](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_month.htm&type=5) formula functions to extract the day and month values from your record's start date for testing in your condition, like:

```
DAY({!Record.StartDate}) = 1 &&
  MONTH({!Record.StartDate}) = 4
```

If the start date is a Datetime, not a Date, you will want to use [DATEVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_datevalue.htm&type=5) to get the date to pass to each of these functions. Note that flow formulae operate on UTC date/time values.

Comment: Beautiful and so much more logical indeed! Thank you!